# wrong date insert when i submit query?

Tags: php, mysql

I insert a date from from `$date=date("Y-m-d")` and this is my query

```
$query="insert into posts (post_title,post_date,post_author,post_image,post_content) 
        values('$title','$date','$author','$image_name','$content')";
```

query run correctly but date insert in database is wrong it takes a day after date.

Ex: 2016-03-10 but it insert 2016-03-11

Comment: Check which time zone you have set. If Sydney, that might be true at this time of day.

Comment: If you want to insert current date better use MySQL `DATE(NOW())` build-in functions within your query rather than PHP `date()`.

Comment: Tnx for reply
but when i execute the same date function in PHP execute correct

Comment: Check your system date???

Comment: my system date also correct.
when i write this code in php "<?php  
 echo date("Y-m-d");  
?>  " it works properly

Comment: **SELECT NOW(),CURDATE(),CURTIME()** . Share Results to make sure it is a DBMS specific problem (tell, if you are testing it locally or on some online domain)

Comment: thx malik..when i used curdate(), insert right date

Answer (score 0):

Please use NOW() or similar SQL-Functions to ensure that it is a database-related issue. What type is this field in your database (varchar, date, datetime, ...)?

I'd also recommend to wrap field- and tablenames in backticks.

Answer (score 0):

The time that is shown is your servers time. if you want time in your time zone you will have to set your timezone.

use this instead.

```html
mysql_query("SET time_zone = '+3:00'");
$query="insert into posts (post_title,post_date,post_author,post_image,post_content) 
            values('$title','$date','$author','$image_name','$content')";
```

The code below will give time in (Africa,Nairobi)

```
mysql_query("SET time_zone = '+3:00'");
```